# YT videos synchronous viewing backend

Tags: java, spring-boot

i want create service that let users watch youtube videos (music tracks for example) together with chatting and video ordering. Server contains rooms and YT videos links in them.

this`Room` class (I remove `@Column` annotations removed)

```
public class Room {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private Date creationDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User owner;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Track> tracks = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(...)
    private Set<User> admins = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(...)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(...)
    private Set<User> blackList = new HashSet<>();
}
```

`Track` class

```
public class Track {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(...)
    private Long id;

    private int trackOrder;
    private String link;
    private LocalDateTime started = LocalDateTime.now();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User requester;
}
```

and `User` class

```
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = UserRole.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(...)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<UserRole> roles = new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(UserRole.ROLE_USER));

    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Room> ownedRooms = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "admins", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Room> adminRooms = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Room> rooms = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Videos playing on clients must be sync, room admin or owner can skip video and server will send message to all users in room by websoket about this.
When video ends server must update video order and send message to clients to play next video in queue.

My problem is here - how server must detect when video ends by itself?

I think about `TimerTask` for each room but I not sure about perfomance of this solve.

Also I read about WEBRTC and I don't understand how to use it in my case
Probably my app arcitecture have fundamental errors,

Comment: You could send the current position from the client via your Websocket Connection. I would say this is nothing critical, so it should be fine if you simply trust the information of a client right?

Comment: If every user in room in a very short period of time sends a WS request for the end of the video - will it create too much load to WS endpoint? And I think I can't trust to client exept if user is admin or owner of room